# Apache vhosts limit and file descriptors limits

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, file-descriptors

I need to host massive websites with SSL and I've read that there is an apache vhosts limit due to file descriptors.

Each domain have a SSL certificate, so unable to do a global virtualhost.

My question is, if 1000 virtualhosts have the directive :

```
ErrorLog /var/logs/apache2/sites.log
```

The system will be limited by the file descriptor or apache will pipe and merge the log ?

Answer (score 1):

Logging is done by the Apache parent process. Multiple virtual hosts that log to the same log file, will not have independent file descriptors for that file.